# How to get global variable and global function inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

At the time of login to my app, I stored the login details and token details inside the session of a class. Now on my aspx page, I have to write a javascript function, which should check if the token got expired within 5 mins or minutes. If then I have to call an API to update the access token with a refresh token. This API I have written in a global class. How can I call this method inside JavaScript? and also how can I get the values stored in the session of the class (ex: login_token_expires_in) inside javascript?

```
`public class GlobalVariables
    {
    public  int login_user_role = 0;
    public  string login_user_name = string.Empty;
    public  string login_user_id = string.Empty;
    public  string login_token = string.Empty;
    public string login_refresh_token = string.Empty;
    public int login_token_expires_in = 0;//1799 sec; 29.9833 minute//1799000
    }
     public class GlobalFunctions
       {
       private bool GetLoginTokenWithRefreshToken(string username, string refresh_token)
        {
           GlobalVariables obj_GlobalVariables =          (GlobalVariables)HttpContext.Current.Session["objGlobalVariableClass"];
           bool status = false;
           string log_data = string.Empty;

           HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
           client.BaseAddress = new Uri(GlobalVariables.WebAPITokenURI);
           HttpResponseMessage response =
           client.PostAsync("e_token",
            new StringContent(string.Format("grant_type=refresh_token&username={0}&refresh_token={1}",
              HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username),
              HttpUtility.UrlEncode(refresh_token)), Encoding.UTF8,
              "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")).Result;
          if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
          {
            string resultJSON = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            e_Token result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<e_Token>(resultJSON);
            obj_GlobalVariables.login_token = result.access_token;
            obj_GlobalVariables.login_refresh_token = result.refresh_token;
            obj_GlobalVariables.login_token_expires_in = Convert.ToInt32(result.expires_in * 1000);//seconds to millisec
            status = true;
         }
         else
         {
            status = false;
         }
         return status;
        }
     }`
```

When login success, stores the login details in GlobalVariables class

```
 `GlobalVariables obj_GlobalVariables = new GlobalVariables();
     obj_GlobalVariables.login_token = result.access_token;
     obj_GlobalVariables.login_token_expires_in = Convert.ToInt32(result.expires_in*1000);//seconds to millisec
    obj_GlobalVariables.login_refresh_token=result.refresh_token;
    obj_GlobalVariables.login_user_name =result.login_user_name;

    etc..`
```

Javascript on Page1.aspx

```
  `<script type="text/javascript">
       var idleSecondsTimer = null;
       idleSecondsTimer = window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);
       function CheckIdleTime() {
      //have to check if time after login >=  login_token_expires_in - 5 seconds
      //then need to call the function  GetLoginTokenWithRefreshToken(username, refresh_token)
           }
       </script>`
```

I want to know how to get the c# global variables and functions inside javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> stored the login details and token details inside the session of a class.

No, no, no!

You  mean you create a class instance, and then SHOVE it into session() to be saved, right? I don't see any "session" in a class here - so this MUST be cleared up by you. You don't have global variables here. And you can't use a static class, since it will be shared/used/the same for all users.

And a global scoped variable will go out of scope. So, you mean you create a class instance, set the values, and THEN save into session(), of which THEN you can retrieve for use on subsequent post-backs.

As for using/having/enjoying those values client side?

Well, you have quite a few options.

You can create a web method that returns the values (so, that would be a client side ajax call).

Another way?

In some cases, I will not make a web method call, and simple shove that server side class into a simple (one) hidden field on the page. (you just shove in the class as serialized), and then client side can grab that simple string, de serialize it into a client side object, and once again, then js client side code on that given page has use of all the values of that class.

It really depends on how many pages, and where you need such values from js code, but I would think in most cases, a web method would be the way to go.

However, lets use the "simple" hidden field, and SEND the class to the client side.

So, say this simple code server side:

For this example, I just shoved all the code right into the existing web page (so you can even cut + paste and try this).

So, say this code:

```
    public class cHotel
    {
        public string FirstName = "";
        public string LastName = "";
        public string HotelName = "";
        public string Description = "";
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadMyData();

        }
    }

    void LoadMyData()
    {
        DataRow drHotel = 
            General.MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = 16").Rows[0];

        cHotel MyHotel = new cHotel();
        MyHotel.FirstName = drHotel["FirstName"].ToString();
        MyHotel.LastName = drHotel["LastName"].ToString();
        MyHotel.HotelName= drHotel["HotelName"].ToString();
        MyHotel.Description = drHotel["Description"].ToString();

        JavaScriptSerializer jsS = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        this.HotelInfo.Value = jsS.Serialize(MyHotel);


    }
```

And the client side markup is this (I do have jQuery, but that one selector could be replaced with getelementByID - the rest is only js code - not jQuery.

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HotelInfo" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

    <div style="padding:40px">

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"
            OnClientClick="test1();return false;"
            />


    </div>

    <script>

        function test1() {
            var MyHotel = JSON.parse($('#HotelInfo').val())

            alert("Hotel name = " + MyHotel.HotelName)
            alert("Description = " + MyHotel.Description)


        }

    </script>
```

So, when I run this page, and click on the button, I get/see this:

[image]

So, the above is a great way to send the class to the page, its simple, and no fancy web methods or anything is required.

And kind of nice, since that hidden field is available to ANY and all routines in the client side js code. So, clean, little code, easy. And the hidden field will survive post-backs and round trips. So, simple, easy, clean, and very little code. and hiddenfield does have viewstate.

However, these days, a LOT of people would suggest that you use a web method, and thus that web method could called from any js code. But, you are now dealing with a asynchronous call, and more moving parts.

However, lets below the above posted c# code, lets add a mebmethod, and give that a shot, shall we?

So, after above code, we now have this:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static cHotel GetHotel()
{
    DataRow drHotel =
        General.MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = 16").Rows[0];

    cHotel MyHotel = new cHotel();
    MyHotel.FirstName = drHotel["FirstName"].ToString();
    MyHotel.LastName = drHotel["LastName"].ToString();
    MyHotel.HotelName = drHotel["HotelName"].ToString();
    MyHotel.Description = drHotel["Description"].ToString();

    return MyHotel;

}
```

Ok, so now in client side, we will call the above web method (ajax call).

So, this:

```
        function test2() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetHotel",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { },
                success: function (response) {
                    var MyHotel = response.d;
                    alert("Hotel name = " + MyHotel.HotelName)
                    alert("Description = " + MyHotel.Description)
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
```

Again, the result would be the same. so, either the "hidden field" trick, or a standard webmethod (that's a end point) call will work.

And I suppose you could make some "single" webmethods that reutrn ONLY one value out of the class. Do keep in mind that while the web methods are "static" (it does not have use of controls on the web page, it can have use of session()).

So, say this:

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static cHotel GetHotel()
    {
        DataRow drHotel =
     bla bla bla
```

Comment: Hi, I have implemented it with webmethod.  
"You mean you create a class instance, and then SHOVE it into session() to be saved, right? " -  yes like as below. Is this a correct way right? 
GlobalVariables obj_GlobalVariables =(GlobalVariables)Session["objGlobalVariableClass"]; 
string loggedinuserName= obj_erms_GlobalVariables.login_user_name;

Comment: On each post-back, you will have to re-create that class, and then re-load from session. There is no concept of persisted global variables. If you don't re-create that class each time, then all users on the system at the same time will be sharing that one same class - and it will not work. So, don't really care what you have or put in that class, but it does not and will not persist between post-backs. And it "sort of" may persist, but that only due to luck, and instant you have multiple users, the whole thing will come crashing down on you. So, you have to restore that class from session

Comment: So yes, what you have looks ok - since you restore obj_GlobalVariables from session, then that looks ok.